# Secure connection to oracle database using apache commons Basic Datasource

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, apache-commons-dbcp

As part of securing all the connection we are enabling ASO in Oracle database, i was able to make secure connection from my java using oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource. But we have projects using apache basic datasource. I tried the below but still the data is not getting encrypted.

```
    BasicDataSource ods = new BasicDataSource();
    ods.setUrl(URL);
    ods.setUsername(user);
    ods.setPassword(password);
    ods.setConnectionProperties("AutoCommit=false;");
    ods.setConnectionProperties("OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL=REQUIRED;");
    ods.setConnectionProperties("OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_TYPES=(AES256);");
    ods.setConnectionProperties("OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CRYPTO_SEED=(sfdsvcfdssegdsvg);");
```

Please let me know if I am missing something in the connection properties. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method ***BasicDataSource#setConnectionProperties(String)*** overrides all properties that been added to the DataSource previously

You need to use method ***BasicDataSource#addConnectionProperty(String, String)*** to add single property:

```
BasicDataSource ods = new BasicDataSource();
ods.addConnectionProperty("OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL", "REQUIRED")
```

or build Properties instance with relevant data, and only then add it to the DataSource:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL", "REQUIRED");
prop.setProperty("OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_TYPES", "(AES256)")
...
BasicDataSource ods = new BasicDataSource();
ods.setConnectionProperties(prop);
```